# Correlation between the perfect market-timing strategy and the market itself?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, market-data, trading, correlation

What would be the correlation between a perfect market-timing strategy [that it always goes long (short) one unit of the market the day before the market goes up (down)] and the market itself, given the market has a symmetric distribution?

I was thinking 1 but apparently it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

if You can time with perfect foresight your returns are always positive and the market returns can be positive or negative. So if you did a simple correlation of these two vectors then it would be less than one.

Comment: And if the market returns distribution is symmetric (positive x return has same probability as -x return) then the correlation is going to be zero.

Comment: Yes. I misread the part about symmetry of the market. Thanks for adding this!